# bash + how to increment variables that contain letters a..z

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rhel

how to increment variables - $var that contain the letters a..z

example:

```
    var=({b..z})
    for x in 1 2 3 4 5
    do
    echo $x,$var

    $var++   ( this is wrong but I need to do something like this )

    done
```

expected output:

```
    1,b
    2,c
    3,d
    4,e
    5,f
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple way:

```
echo "$x,$var"
var="$(echo $var | tr '[a-y]z' '[b-z]a')"
```

Comment: why trailing `a` in `[...]a` ?

Comment: Absent direction for what an "incremented" `z` would become, I opted to have it "wrap around" to `a`.

Comment: In POSIX compliant `tr` implementations, that would convert `z` to `]`. POSIXly: `tr a-z b-za`. To be compatible with both POSIX and SysV: `tr '[a-y]z' '[b-z]a'`

Answer (score 2):

You have an array; just index it:

```
var=( {b..z} )
for ((x=0; x<5; x++)); do
    echo "$x, ${var[x+1]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paste -d, <(  printf  "%s\n" {1..25} ) <(  printf "%s\n" {b..z} )
```

producing:

```
1,b
2,c
3,d
4,e
5,f
6,g
.
.
```

For a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
paste (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```